# Qt 5.0 QScreen solidfill function

Tags: c++, qt, screen, qtcore

I have to fill the screen with a solid color. It looks like in qt 4.8 version this is supported using the following function.

```
void QScreen::solidFill ( const QColor & color, const QRegion & region )   [virtual]
```

Now in Qt5 I see that this function is deprecated in QScreen class. I tried something like this:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QPixmap qpix = screen->grabWindow(0, 0, 0, desktop()->width(),
                  desktop()->height());
qpix.fill(Qt::black);
```

I tried using QSplashScreen and it works. It looks like an overlay screen than something really drawing on screen.

Is there is a straight replacement for this?  perhaps close to blit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an embedded application? What platform plugin are you using?

Comment: yes. we are using wayland.